# String terminator for converting Time Strings

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a String Array like

```
First[i]
```

In this array, the values are Like

```
"00hr:00min:17sec"
"00hr:03min:18sec"
"00hr:05min:25sec"
"01hr:39min:44sec"
```

Now I take another string array like

```
Secound[j]
"17sec Ago"
"3min Ago"
"5min Ago"
"1hr Ago"
```

How can I convert first string array to seconds string array?

Comment: You could find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. parse the string into components; possibly by position, possibly with `Parse`, possibly with regex
2. decide what rules you want for each output
3. use it

For example:

```
static string SimplifyTime(string value)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(value, "([0-9]{2})hr:([0-9]{2})min:([0-9]{2})sec");
    if (!match.Success) return value;
    int val = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (val > 0) return val + "hr Ago";
    val = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (val > 0) return val + "min Ago";
    val = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return val + "sec Ago";
}
static void Main()
{
    string[] values = {
        "00hr:00min:17sec",
        "00hr:03min:18sec",
        "00hr:05min:25sec",
        "01hr:39min:44sec"
    };
    var converted = Array.ConvertAll(values, SimplifyTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            string[] first ={"00hr:00min:17sec",
"00hr:03min:18sec",
"00hr:05min:25sec",
"01hr:39min:44sec"};
            string[] second = new string[first.Length];
            string pattern = @"([0-9]{2})hr:([0-9]{2})min:([0-9]{2})sec";
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(first[i],pattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    int hour = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    if (hour > 0)
                        second[i] = hour + "hr ago";
                    else
                    {
                        int min = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
                        if (min > 0)
                            second[i] = min + "min ago";
                        else
                        {
                            int sec = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
                            if (sec > 0)
                                second[i] = sec + "sec ago";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

you will using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: you need to be a little careful with `\d` - it matches things like ٣٤٥٦٧٨

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that before.

Comment: @ojlovecd Actually, these symbols are digits as well but Arabic. Their range in unicode is 1632-1641. So you can parse matched string into `int` but it's nothing more than head-ache.

Comment: @PLB Thanks so much. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert it to a `TimeSpan`:

```
string[] strTimeSpans = new[]{"00hr:00min:17sec","00hr:03min:18sec","00hr:05min:25sec","01hr:39min:44sec"};
TimeSpan[] timespans = strTimeSpans
    .Select(s => {
        var parts = s.Split(':');
        int hour = int.Parse(parts[0].Substring(0, 2));
        int min = int.Parse(parts[1].Substring(0, 2));
        int sec = int.Parse(parts[2].Substring(0, 2));
        return new TimeSpan(hour, min, sec);
    }).ToArray();
```

Then you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248/284240) to get a readable `TimeSpan`, i have added it to a method:

```
public static string GetReadableTimespan(TimeSpan ts)
{
    const int SECOND = 1;
    const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;
    double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);

    if (delta < 0)
    {
        return "not yet";
    }
    if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
    {
        return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";
    }
    if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
    {
        return "a minute ago";
    }
    if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
    {
        return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";
    }
    if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
    {
        return "an hour ago";
    }
    if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
    {
        return ts.Hours + " hours ago";
    }
    if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
    {
        return "yesterday";
    }
    if (delta < 30 * DAY)
    {
        return ts.Days + " days ago";
    }
    if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
    {
        int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
        return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
    }
    else
    {
        int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
        return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
    }
}
```

Now this....

```
foreach (TimeSpan ts in timespans)
    Console.WriteLine(GetReadableTimespan(ts));
```

outputs:

```
17 seconds ago
3 minutes ago
5 minutes ago
1 hours ago
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/YyCPiq)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the regularal expression answers are better and more professional. But i also post another approach more amatuer.

```
  string[] First = new string[] { "00hr:00min:17sec",
                                        "00hr:03min:18sec",
                                        "00hr:05min:25sec",
                                        "01hr:39min:44sec"};

     string[] Secound = new string[First.Length];

     for(int i =0 ;i<First.Length;i++)
     {
        string hour = First[i].Split(':')[0].Replace("hr", "");
        string min = First[i].Split(':')[1].Replace("min", "");
        string sec = First[i].Split(':')[2].Replace("sec", "");
        if (Convert.ToInt32(hour) > 0)
        {
            hour = hour + "hr Ago";
            Secound[i] = hour;
            continue;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(min) > 0)
        {
            min = min + "min Ago";
            Secound[i] = min;
            continue;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(sec) > 0)
        {
            sec = sec + "sec Ago";
            Secound[i] = sec;
            continue;
        }
     }
```